# POST in django. How does a user update?

Tags: python, django, post

I'm brand new to django and fairly new to programming in general. I've done the django tutorial and searched the web for an answer to this question, but to no avail, so now I'm here. I am confused how post works with django. All of the tutorials I've looked at how have a return function in views that displays the webpage. I get that. But then how does a user update data if the page is being rendered from that return statement? After the return there can't be any more updates because the function stops, right? What am I missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm getting fairly desperate here.

Comment: in the tutorial dont you save posts?

Comment: [Part 4 of the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial04/) has an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One pattern for Django views (by no means the only pattern) is to check the request method (GET or POST) at the beginning of the view. If it is POST, then handle the incoming data (*before* the view returns), and then return either a rendered template, or a redirect.

```
def view_function(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if data_is_valid(request.POST):
            save_data(request.POST)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/somewhere/good')
        else:
            return render('template', {'errors': what_went_wrong}
    else:
        return render('template')
```

Answer (score 0):

The user updates data in the logic of the `view` function.  That is to say, if the user wishes to update something, you place the update logic in the `view` function before the `return`.  For example, you would do this:

```
def update(request):
    item = <some model>.objects.get(<something>)
    <more code>
    return <something>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually an edit view function contains two parts -- one for updating data, and the other for displaying the update form. For example,

```
def user_edit(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':            # is this a save action?
        # save the user data

        user_id = request.POST.get('user_id')
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        description = request.POST.get('description')

        user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        user.username = username
        user.description = description
        user.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/')          # redirect to index

    else:

        # show the edit form
        user_id = request.GET.get('user_id')
        user = User.object.get(id=user_id)

        return render_to_response('/user/edit.html', { 'user': user })
```

There are many different choices for the `if request.method == 'POST'` line. You can also use `if request.POST.get('user_id')` to check if specified field is set, to determine if this is a save action.